# How to assign of a variable to another variable with specific condition in R?

Tags: r, variables, vector

Suppose `x=c(5,6,8,9,10)`, I would like to create another variable `y` of length `8`. The `3rd`, `5th` and `7th` position should be zero and the rest of the positions are filled with `x`- values. 
The expected `y` is `c(5,6,0,8,0,9,0,10)`

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can create an empty vector of length 8, assign values of `x` to `y` removing index at `pos`.

```
pos <- c(3, 5, 7)
y <- integer(length = 8)
y[-pos] <- x
y
#[1]  5  6  0  8  0  9  0 10
```